# Failed to load resources error 404 while deploying create-react-app

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, deployment

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thank you!

I can run my website fine locally, but am having problems when deploying it in production. When I run `npm run deploy`, it should automatically build into production.

[image]

Here's part of my `package.json` for the deploy command:

```
{
    "name": "barrex",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "homepage": "https://patrickhuang94.github.io/barrex",
    "devDependencies": {
        "gh-pages": "^0.12.0",
        "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",    
        "deploy": "npm run build&&gh-pages -d build"
    }
}
```

Everything on my `gh-pages` is set up correctly. When I run the URL I specified in my 'homepage' field ([Barrex](https://patrickhuang94.github.io/barrex)), it's redirecting to my custom domain. But my custom domain can't find the .js files that was supposed to be created with `npm run deploy`. Can someone explain why it runs ok on local machine, but can't find resources in production?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As it says in the screenshot, the project was built assuming it would be hosted at `/barrex/`.
However you are serving it from the server root.

Change `homepage` in `package.json` to your custom domain (`http://www.barrexus.com/`). Next time you build, it will infer `/` as the path project is hosted on, and use that instead.

Comment: I have no idea how you got to this question (was it via my Reddit post?) but thank you so much, this worked just fine. Love your work :)

Comment: three years later and this was still the solution for me! thanks!